# Total sets in Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

We call the set total if its linear span is dense in a given normed space.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $D$ be a total set in $X$.

For the sequence $\{T_n\}$ of bounded operators on $X$. we have the following
$\|(T_n - T)x\| \to 0$ for all $x \in D$, where $T$ is some bouned linear operator on $X$.
Does it imply that $\{T_n\}$ converges strongly to $T$ on whole $X$?

I think that the answer is yes, but my solution seems to be too easy.

Let $x \in X$, then $x= \sum_{k \geq 0} c_kx_k$, where $c_k \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x_k \in D$.
$$\|(T_n - T)x \| = \| \sum_{k \geq 0} c_k (T_n - T)x_k \| \leq \sum_{k \geq 0}|c_k| \|(T_n - T)x_k \| \to 0, $$ where we use the continuity of our operators and properties of the norm.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know that $x$ can be written as the infinite linear combination of elements in $D$? I'm fairly certain that's not true, though I can't think of a counterexample. Though the essence of the proof is there, you can approximate $x$ with a finite combination of elements in $D$ and use continuity to show that $\|(T_n-T)x\|\to 0$

Comment: You are right, I just thought about $D$ as a Schauder basis.

Comment: @minimalrho is correct, total sets are not necessarily complete in infinite dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: Are the $T_n$ uniformly bounded?

Comment: Yes, Banach--Steinhaus theorem answers this question.

Comment: My category knowledge is weak; is it obvious the  span of $D$ is of the second category in $X$?

Comment: Thanks I was sure, that it has to be second category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try this.

$X = l_2$, Hilbert space, $D$ the elements with finitely many nonzero components.  Then $D$ is dense, so certainly total.  For each $n$, let $P_n$ be the projection on coordinates $n$ and higher.
$$
P_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n,x_{n+1},\cdots) = (0,0,0,\cdots,0,x_n,x_{n+1},\cdots)
$$

Let $T_n = nP_n$.  Now $\|T_n x\| \to 0$ for all $x \in  D$, since (for each such $x$) it is eventually zero.
But $\|T_n x\| \to 0$ fails for some $x \in X$.  For example: $x = (1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\cdots)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $D = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_k \} \subset l_2$.  $D$ is dense in $l_2$. (Note that $D$ is of the first category in $l_2$.)

Define $T_n x = \langle e_n, x \rangle e_1$. $\|T_n\| =1$ for all $n$. However if $x \in D$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n x = 0$, but clearly $T_n$ does not converge to $0$.

If $D$ was of the second category in $X$, the conclusion would be true by Banach Steinhaus.